# Sequelize returns date earlier than received

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

Good morning, I have a problem, in which Sequelize returns to the day before the date passed to the backend and to this it also adds a default time, 23:00:00.
In short, I in the frontend select a date through the datepicker and send it to the backend. When logging into the Backend console, it appears correctly, but when I send it to a where clause, it assumes the previous day of that date and adds a time and format. That is, if you select the date 2020-07-11, it will put in the where 2020-07-10 23:00:00 +00: 00.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I send code and print from the backend console to show the date.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var Viagem = require('../../model/viagem');
var pedido_viagem = require('../../model/pedido_viagem');
var Estado = require('../../model/estado');
var Pessoa = require('../../model/pessoa');
var Partida = require('../../model/freguesias');
var Chegada = require('../../model/freguesias');
const sequelize = require('../../model/database');
const viagem = require('../../model/viagem');

const cmv_cont = {}
sequelize.sync()

cmv_cont.pendentes_data_inicio = async(req, res) => {
    const data_inicio_filtragem = req.query;
console.log(data_inicio_filtragem.data_inicio);
    const data = await Viagem.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Pessoa,
                attributes: ['p_nome', 'u_nome']
            }],
            where: [
                {estado: "2"}, 
                {pago_pela_cmv: "0" },
                {data_viagem: "" + data_inicio_filtragem.data_inicio }],
            order: [
                ['data_viagem', 'ASC']
            ],

        })
        .then(function(data) {

            return data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Erro: ' + error);
            return error;
        });
    res.json({ success: true, data: data });

}

module.exports = cmv_cont;
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind is sequelize timezone configuration.

Based on your code I suppose you're from Portugal so the timezone is `UTC+00:00`, however, Daylight saving time for Europe/Lisbon is `UTC+01:00` from **March 29** until **October 25**

Sequelize tries to save all Datetimes as `UTC+00:00`

Try to execute the following:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

const date = moment('2020-07-11'); // moment("2020-07-11T00:00:00.000")
date.utc(); // moment.utc("2020-07-10T23:00:00.000+00:00")
```

It's standard behavior and probably configuration that you want. When you fetch created `Viagem` the date should be returned in your local format.

Comment: I solved a problem putting a variable of type `Sequelize.DataTypes.DATEONLY on model` . Thanks anyway